# Exclude certain files and folders when tagging in Git

Tags: git, tagging

I have a master branch with folders I want to track but do not want to distribute in a release. Is there a way to tag out a release but exclude certain folders?

Comment: A tag names a commit, it cannot be attached to pieces of a tree that is identified by a commit.

Answer (score 2):

'Fraid not.

As Linus once said, Git wonders what happened to that part of the project, not what happened to that file. A project is tracked as a whole in Git, not individually.

But what you could do is tag your release and then write a short export script that would

```
checkout a given tag
rsync using --exclude to a temp deployment folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you track these secret folders in the same project as public folders, there is no way to do it.

Maybe you could use git submodules (http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html), but in this case you'll loose some integrity.